# Is there a way to list objects with keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shader-nodes

I have many instances of the same object. The object's materials are linked. I selected one instance and started to add keyframes to change the colour in a Color Ramp node. I've since clicked off the object and cannot remember or find the instance with the keyframes.

- I'm sure I've clicked on each of the objects - nothing.
- I can't see any way to filter keyframes in Outliner.
- I can't see anything of use on the Dope Sheet.

I'm sure this is so rudimentary, Blender experts wouldn't give it a second thought, but I'm stuck.

Grateful for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. Somehow, I was looking at the Dope Sheet rather than the Timeline area.

[image]

The Timeline area had been reduced down to just the title (1) at the bottom of the screen - without me noticing what had happened. (The Dopesheet and Timeline look very similar). Like this:

[image]